# what does a method of which name is same with the class name do in Objective c?

Tags: objective-c, classname

Sorry I saw a piece of code in https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/General/Conceptual/CocoaEncyclopedia/ClassClusters/ClassClusters.html, I don't understand what does the method with the same name as the class name does in Objective c?

```
#import <foundation/foundation.h>

@interface MonthArray : NSArray

{
}



+ monthArray; // what is this function, a constructor?

- (unsigned)count;

- (id)objectAtIndex:(unsigned)index;



@end
```

Is there any special meaning to define a function using the same name as the class name? A constructor?

Comment: A convenience constructor. Nothing more. In old times / non-arc it used to create autoreleased object which was kind of handy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A class method with the same name as the class is usually a **factory method**. This is a common convention, however it's not required or enforced by the language.

For example `[NSArray array]` returns an empty array. It's just like `[[NSArray alloc] init]`.

The `+` next to the method name makes it a class method, meaning you can invoke it on the class directly: `[MonthArray monthArray]`.

Answer (score 1):

It's a convention that allows for more readable code and convenience. If you wanted to build this behavior in your own code, you would do something like the following...

```
// DogClass.h
@interface DogClass : NSObject

+ (instancetype)dog;

- (instancetype)initWithDogName:(NSString *)name ownerName:(NSString *)ownerName birthYear:(NSNumber *)birthYear breed:(NSString *)breed;

@end

// DogClass.m
@implementation DogClass

+ (instancetype)dog {
DogClass *aDog = [[DogClass alloc] initWithDogName:@"" ownerName:@"" birthYear:@(0) breed:@""];
return aDog;
}

- (instancetype)initWithDogName:(NSString *)name ownerName:(NSString *)ownerName birthYear:(NSNumber *)birthYear breed:(NSString *)breed {
    if (self = [super init]) {
        self.name = name;
        self.ownerName = ownerName;
        self.birthYear = birthYear;
        self.dateAdded = [NSDate date];
        self.breed = breed;
    }
    return self;
}
@end
```

Now you can init a DogClass in one of two ways, as they init in the same way...

```
DogClass = [DogClass dog];
```

**or**

```
DogClass = [[DogClass alloc] initWithDogName:@"" ownerName:@"" birthYear:@(0) breed:@""]
```